# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of com.finance.biblioteca.service.dto.LibroDTO out of START_ARRAY token;

Tags: java, json, parsing, postman

```
[
    {
        "id": 52,
        "titolo": "Le solite sospette",
        "categorie": [],
        "autori": [],
        "editori": [],
        "anno_uscita": "2015",
        "idCollana": 1,
        "disponibilita": 1,
        "prezzo": 9
    }
]
```

Can I solve this error? This appear when I want to add a new object

```
@PostMapping(URL)
public LibroDTO newLibro(@RequestBody LibroDTO libroDTO)
```

> "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.finance.biblioteca.service.dto.LibroDTO` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.finance.biblioteca.service.dto.LibroDTO` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"

Comment: Can you show me LibroDTO

Comment: this is my dto:                                                                                                     
       private Long id;
 private String titolo;
 private List<LibroCategoriaDTO> categorie;
 private List<LibroAutoreDTO> autori;
 private List<LibroEditoreDTO> editori;
 private String anno_uscita;
 private Long idCollana;
 private int disponibilita;
 private int prezzo;

Comment: Do you don't use JsonProperty ?

Comment: no, i never used that, can you link a documentation about ?

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON string starts with `[`, so it's an array, while the method `newLibro` takes a single istance of `LibroDTO`.
You should either change the signature of that method to:
`public LibroDTO newLibro(@RequestBody List<LibroDTO> libri)`
or change your JSON to

```
{ "id": 52, "titolo": "Le solite sospette", "categorie": [], "autori": [], "editori": [], "anno_uscita": "2015", "idCollana": 1, "disponibilita": 1, "prezzo": 9 }
```

in order to pass a single object.

Comment: and the error is:  "message": "query did not return a unique result: 9; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 9",

Comment: @Max It seems unrelated to the original question. Could you please add the stacktrace and the related code to the question? Anyway it seems that you did a query that returns a list of object, but you tried to assign the result to a non-collection variable. For example: `LibroDTO libro = libriRepository.findByAuthor(autore);` instead of `List<LibroDTO> libri = libriRepository.findByAuthor(autore);`